How to wait until element is visible for limited time?
I am waiting for a notification into portal after creating a service. Notification is not always visible on top and time is not fixed for it (I mean it takes max 10 seconds to show. If not visible within a 10 seconds will not appear on screen).
Now my test case is:
After creating a service, I want to wait until notification visible on the screen but want to bound it in a time. I can wait till 10 seconds. If notification visible within a 10 seconds, verify the text and if not visible in a time, reload the page.
I tried below one, but it is not working as expected:
export function verifyNotificationOfServiceCreation($text) {

    cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
        const $el = $body.find(getNotificationOnTop()); // Locate the element within the DOM
        if ($el.length && $el.is(':visible')) {
            //Verify notification text
            cy.wrap($el).should('have.text', $text);
            //Verify secondary text
            cy.contains('Refresh to see changes on page').should('be.visible')
            cy.contains('REFRESH', {matchCase: true}).should('be.visible').click()
            expect($el.text().trim()).to.equal('Expected Text');; // Element is found, visible, and condition met
        }
        return !$el.length; // Return true if element doesn't exist to exit wait
    })

}
It gives an error message 'cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.'

What is the code for getNotificationOnTop()?

Getting a locator of notification. Nothing else.
export function getNotificationOnTop(){
return cy.get('.css-1mo2vwx')
}

Show it in the question - there may be a better approach, so maybe it is significant.

Also, you said "want to bound it in a time" I assume that translates to "I want to query with 10 seconds timeout". Can you confirm that is the intention? There is currently no timeout in the code.

Yes, I want wait until 10 seconds. If within 10 seconds notification appear on the screen, want to assert text and perform other actions if not want reload the page. But don't want to fail a test case.
